# Why ssh-keygen does not output 32 bytes but instead 1612 chars?

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

My goal is to create my own TLS handshake server, so I can understand how encryption between server-client works. I am following [this](https://tls13.ulfheim.net/) reference. In the `Server Key Exchange Generation` section from the reference, the private key length are said to be 32 bytes. But the example length is 64 bytes. Also, `ssh-keygen` output 1612 chars for `private.key` and 567 chars for `private.pub`.

My expected result: The `private.pub` should be used as is in `Server Hello` section of the reference which sends the public key with length 32 bytes to the client.

My actual result: The `ssh-keygen` or even `keytool` (I can't read the file with IntelliJ IDEA, so right now, I am avoiding it) output more than 32 bytes.

The cmd used

```
ssh-keygen
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -validity 7 -keystore keystore
```

test\experiment\tls\tls\TLSHandshake.java

```
class TLSHandshakeTest {

  @Test
  void doHandshake() {
    String key = "MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VuBCIEIJCRkpOUlZaXmJmam5ydnp+goaKjpKWmp6ipqqusra6v";
    byte[] bytes = key.getBytes();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
    // output: 64 instead of 32, does this mean that the `private.pub` file must be processed with an encoder?
    System.out.println(bytes.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: The key is 64 characters, the byte array `bytes` will never be smaller that that.

Comment: @Anders Lindgren Could you help me about how does server encode public key to 32 bytes? Assuming we configure the server to take keystore gwnerated by `keytool` or public key generated by `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: A TLS1.3 (or earlier) server can't use _just_ a publickey, and in particular can't use the publickey file generated by `ssh-keygen`. It normally needs a _certificate_ which _contains_ the publickey but also lots of other information (`keytool -genkeypair` creates such a certificate, albeit an untrusted self-signed one), _and_ the privatekey. PS: you tagged TLS1.2, but your Q does not involve TLS1.2.

Comment: Also dupe at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403808/private-key-length-bytes https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90169/rsa-public-key-and-private-key-lengths https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102508/why-is-openssl-key-length-different-from-specified-bytes https://serverfault.com/questions/267522/ssh-keys-why-is-id-rsa-larger-than-id-rsa-pub and I'm certain I've seen more but haven't managed to get google to find them for me.

Answer (score 1):

The 32 byte (128 bit) secret key produced in the "server key exchange generation" step is not the RSA private key.  It is actually the key for the symmetric encryption algorithm that will be used to protect application data.

What happens is that the RSA asymmetric algorithm is used to establish identities, and to protect the negotiation.  During this process the symmetric algorithm is agreed and 128 bit secret keys are generated and exchanged (securely).  Once the session is established, the 128 bit keys are use to encrypt and decrypt the data sent over the connection.

Why don't they use RSA for everything?

Basically, it is too computationally expensive to use RSA (or any other asymmetric algorithm) for bulk data encryption / decryption.  The symmetric (block cypher) algorithms are much more efficient.  (So you could view the initial negotiation as a "key distribution mechanism" for the session private keys.)

As for the size of the private and public key files generated by `ssh-keygen`:

1. The files contain more than just one key:

   - The public key file contains the value of the `modulus` and the public exponent `e`
   - The private key file usually contains the values of the `modulus` and both `e` and the private exponent `d` and several more values (`p`, `q`, `dp`, `dq`, `qinvp`).  This is part of why the private key file is bigger than the public key file!
2. The file contents are encoded in ASN.1 which adds some extra type headers.
3. The (binary) ASN.1 encoded data is then base64 encoded which uses roughly one ASCII character for each 6 bits of data (plus some padding).
4. Some additional stuff is added to that:

   - The private key has line breaks added, along with "PEM" header and trailer lines.
   - The public key has the name of the algorithm (e.g. "ssh-rsa") and a "comment" added which serves to identify the person the key belongs to.  (The comment is largely ignored by SSH ... but it is useful when you are manually adding or removing keys from an "authorized keys" file.)

For later versions of OpenSSH, OpenSSH key formats may be used instead of OpenSSL key formats.  These use XDR encoding in place of ASN.1.  This may be relevant to you if you are trying to write your own SSH implementation<sup>1</sup>.

---

As we can see, the "private key" file generated by `ssh-keygen` actually contains both the public and private keys for the keypair.  Indeed it is possible to recover the keypair's public key from a private key file; e.g.

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Refer to [Create a public ssh key from the private key](https://serverfault.com/questions/52285/) for more details.

---

<sup>1 - To be honest, I can't see the point of doing that.  It is a lot of effort ... just to learn a bunch of details that you most likely don't need to know.</sup>

Comment: Basically right, but: the 'prime numbers' in RSA usually mean the _factors_ p,q, and neither of those is in the publickey. Publickey has modulus and public _exponent_ e while privatekey usually has modulus _and_ both e and  private exponent d _and_ several more values (p,q,dp,dq,qinvp) used for the Chinese Remainder Theorem aka CRT about which there are many existing Qs on several Stacks. Neither e nor d is necessarily prime, although e is _often_ chosen to be a fixed small prime. ...

Comment: Thanks.  Incorporated those details (in shortened form).

Comment: ... Older versions of OpenSSH created OpenSSL format privatekey files which are as you describe, but 6.5 up optionally and 7.8 up by default use a different format which is NOT ASN.1 encoded; it uses an OpenSSH-defined XDR-style encoding, after which it is 'PEM-ized' (base64-encoded with linebreaks, header and trailer) in the same fashion (and with roughly the same expansion). The OpenSSH-format publickey is _never_ ASN.1. Also the symmetric (session) keys are usually called secret, not private.